# align widgets to the left and right of the screen in flutter

Tags: flutter

i am having problems trying to align my widgets.  the left side is aligning correctly but the right side is off a little bit.

here is my code

this is the code for the card view

```
ListView itemList(List<IncomeData> items, AppDatabase database, BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: items.map((IncomeData income) {
        return Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 5.0, 15.0,5.0),
            child: new Card(  //listView(income),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 20.0,0.0),
                child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    listView(income),
                    new ButtonBar(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new RaisedButton.icon(
                          label: const Text('Edit'),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.edit,),
                          color: colorPrimary,
                          onPressed: () {
                            _navigateAndDisplaySelection(context, income);
                           /* Navigator.push(context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddEditIncomeForm(incomeData: income)));*/
                            },
                        ),
                        new RaisedButton.icon(
                          label: const Text('Delete'),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                          color: colorPrimary,
                          onPressed: () {
                            //database.deleteEntry(income);
                            //deleteConfirmation(income, database);
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) {
                                return CheckBoxAlertDialog(transactionType: delete, data: income, database: database,);
                              }
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          )
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
```

this is the code for the content of the card view

```
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 8),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(common_functions(incomeList.dateReceived.toString()),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold )),
            Spacer(),

            //Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
            Text("Not Received"),

            Switch(
              value: isSwitched,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  isSwitched = value;
                  print(isSwitched);
                });
              },
              activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
              activeColor: Colors.green,
            ),
          ]
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: green,
              child: Icon(Icons.attach_money, color: white,),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(incomeList.category,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold )),
                    Text(incomeList.frequency + " | " + incomeList.depositAcct, style: TextStyle(color: grey, fontSize: 15)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("\$" + incomeList.expectedAmount.toStringAsFixed(2),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: green , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold ) ),
                Text(incomeList.status,  style: TextStyle(color: grey, fontSize: 15)),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

if you take a look at the pic attached, the buttons and the top switch is not align properly to the number $68.00.  see the red line i drawed.  the switch on top is off to the left by a few spaces and also the buttons are the bottom are not align exactly to $68.00

am i doing something wrong that the widgets are not aligning to the red line as $68.00 is? how can i change my code to properly align all the widgets on the right side?  thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Is  listView(income) is content of card view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ButtonBar it's buttonPadding parameter. Just be sure not to use any horizontal padding with it (right or left), since it will split it between the buttons. You will have to add a left padding for the buttons inside the ButtonBar.

I've attached an example for it and for the Switch widget, which doesn't have any properties to modify this behavior, but you can always use Transform.translate to overcome this.

```dart
Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset(10.0, 0.0),
                    child: Switch(
                      value: true,
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                      activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                      activeColor: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              ButtonBar(
                buttonPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton.icon(
                    label: const Text('Edit'),
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.edit,
                    ),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                    child: RaisedButton.icon(
                      label: const Text('Delete'),
                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```